# Is there a method to check if an array includes one value in SQLite?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sqlite-json1

Let's say, we have this SQLite table with id=number and tags=text:

```
| id   | tags                |  
| ---- | ------------------- |   
| 1    | ["love","sadness"]  |    
| 2    | ["love"]            |   
| 3    | ["happiness","joy"] |
```

Is there a way to only return the rows which their cells `tags` include "love" for example,
like this command in MySQL : `SELECT * from my_table WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '"love"')` in SQLite.

I use this with the library `sql.js` wtih node.js

Answer (score 16):

If your version of sqlite has the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension compiled in:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM json_each(tags) WHERE value = 'love')
ORDER BY id;
```

will return

```
id  tags               
--  -------------------
1   ["love","sadness"] 
2   ["love"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```sql
SELECT * from my_table WHERE tags LIKE '%"love"%';
```

Keyword `LIKE` lets you query partial information in the column and it's used in `WHERE` clause just like operators `=`, `IN`, `BETWEEN`

Note:

- The percent sign % wildcard matches any sequence of zero or more characters.
- The underscore _ wildcard matches any single character.

Comment: Ok thanks, but it's look like a regex workaround not a real json filter function

Comment: It's either that or building sql.js with json1 extension enabled from the repository. For simple arrays in your example use this workarounnd.